remove common substring with groupby method
I would like to remove the duplicates with common substring, the common substring is shortest string in dataframe.
I try below code and it works as expected but I would like to improve the code. after groupby, the filter logic is added by reformat function.
import re
import pandas as pd
import tabulate

def dumpdf(df):
    s = tabulate.tabulate(df, tablefmt='plain', headers='keys', showindex=True)
    print(s)
    return

def reformat(df):
    dfg = df.groupby('name')
    flag = False
    for name,df in dfg:
        item = []
        df = df.sort_values(by="package", key=lambda x: x.str.len())
        data = []
        for idx,row in df.iterrows():
            pkg = row['package']
            df.loc[df['package'].str.startswith(pkg, na=False), 'package'] = pkg
        df = df[df.duplicated(['package'], keep='first') == False]
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
        if len(df) > 0:
            if flag == False:
                flag = True
                out = df
            else:
                out = pd.concat([out,df],ignore_index=True)
    return out

def main():

    data = [
        ['A','com.example'],
        ['A','com.example.a'],
        ['A','com.example.b.c'],
        ['A','com.fun'],
        ['B','com.demo'],
        ['B','com.demo.b.c'],
        ['B','com.fun'],
        ['B','com.fun.e'],
        ['B','com.fun.f.g']
        ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','package'])

    df = reformat(df)
    df = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg('\n'.join)

    dumpdf(df)
    return

main()


Output:
    name    package
 0  A       com.fun
            com.example
 1  B       com.fun
            com.demo



You need to find the package names which are the root names, which you can do by testing whether any other package is a prefix of the current package name:
def is_root_package(pkg, df):
    return not any(pkg.startswith(p) and len(pkg) > len(p) for p in df['package'])

Now mask the dataframe using this function and groupby the name:
mask = df['package'].apply(is_root_package, df=df)

out = df[mask].groupby('name', as_index=False).agg('\n'.join)

Output:
  name               package
0    A  com.example\ncom.fun
1    B     com.demo\ncom.fun

If it's possible that a group might contain all values that have a prefix in another group e.g. there's a com.fun in the df but a particular group has only com.fun.* packages, you will need to check packages on a per-group basis. You can do that with this code:
# sample data
data = {
 'name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
 'package': ['com.example', 'com.example.a', 'com.example.b.c', 'com.fun', 'com.demo', 'com.demo.b.c', 'com.fun.e', 'com.fun.e.f', 'com.fun.e.g']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_root_packages(g):
    return '\n'.join(pkg for pkg in g if not any(pkg.startswith(p) and len(pkg) > len(p) for p in g))

out = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg(get_root_packages)

Output:
  name               package
0    A  com.example\ncom.fun
1    B   com.demo\ncom.fun.e


Good answer, one case I am thinking is the root project check scope. now it's the whole dataframe, how can we limit root check  per group? Maybe we have different root levels.

@beetlej sorry about slow reply, busy day. I've added an edit that will do the root check on a per group basis.
